# Should I use Eloquent ORM or create big joins by Fluent?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Well, I'm using Eloquent ORM for a project that I'm developing, but it is bugging me with the performance issue. When I use only its own methods, I can see by its query log that it creates a lot of queries.

I'm trying to fetch data from a main table with 4 other tables, one related to it one-to-one and the others many-to-many. Eloquent creates about 6-7 queries for it, and that makes me afraid of performance issues. Then, I remove Eloquent's methods and create jumbo queries with Fluent, using lots of joins, which makes me lose code readability and practicity.

What I really need to know is: Does Eloquent sacrifice performance? Should I stick to it, or use just Fluent? And what is better, a few big joined queries or more small ones?

Comment: In fact that's totally up to you and your app. Create it using `Eloquent`. It will be likely easier and quicker. Then when you need to improve performance, refactor what needs to be refactored. Also there are other ways to improve it - cache to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to extend Sebastian's answer.

I too have many to many relationships or even one to many relationships.

I have actually melded Eloquent's style of programming (its easier on the eyes) with a bit of a joint hack with Fluent. Please be reminded that Eloquent is an extension of Fluent so your not sacrificing unless you are doing bat queries.

If you do a User and then Phone model with a One to one or one to many (a user can have many phone number)

and you simply where()->get() and then $users->phone - this will make eloquent run a select * for each ID. This is where Eager Loading (as referenced by Sebastian but too short to actually explain) is used where it prefetch all the IDs required and eager load the IDs (you can verify this by running a query log profiler).

The added bonus of this is that you can eagerload many relationships like this.

So its not cut dry solution of "is Eloquent providing a performance hit" if you dont use it the right way.

Now here is a small example to how I put both eloquent and fluent to use:
Within Book Model - I have defined a Scope function which is a relationship function:

```
   public function scopeLicensorStatus($query, $licensor_status)
    {
        $query->select('book.*')
            ->leftJoin('licensors as l', 'l.id', '=', 'book.licensor_id')
            ->where('l.status','=',$licensor_status);
    }

    $bookData = Book::
        ->LicensorStatus('active')
        ->where('book.status','=', 'active')
        ->whereIN('book.id',$recommendedIds)
        ->take($limit)
        ->skip($offset)
        ->get();
```

what does this do is do the Join for me as a function and let me chain up the commands fro the outside. In the end (if you do toSQL() instead of get()) you will achieve a single query that will match raw SQL, however as you can see a) the code is reusable if you forsee to reuse the join with other constraints, b) your not sacrificing speed since the end game query is a single one (just need to write it properly), c) looks nicer and readable which is why we like eloquent.

Hope this answer helps you to dive a bit more into eloquent

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. So, if I am using Eager Loading instead of Fluent, which makes me perform 2-3 additional queries (which would be achieved by Fluent using some joins and ending up with lots of redundant information), it will probably not affect performance significantly in the server, will it?

Comment: As I explained - Eager Loading doens't eliminate joins. What it does is that instead of taking the IDs (or relationship) between two tables and rerun them individually, it will pre-load those ID and then load it in on the second query (hence solving N+1 iteration). For one to many it works very very well. for many to many you might need to do some manipulation. As i gave in my example how i kept joins and use eloquent at the same time.